# How can solve Error with CNN Model Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have this model with Keras:

```
model.add(Conv1D(4,kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
                               input_shape=(tablon_vectores_train.shape[1], 
                                            tablon_vectores_train.shape[2])
                               #,padding='same'
                               )
                       )

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model.add(Conv1D(6,kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1) )
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
model = model.fit(
        X
        , Y
        , epochs=50, batch_size=10
        , validation_split= 0.25
        , verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

When I do the predict code:

`predict = model.predict(X_test)`

I have this error:

> AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'.

What can I do?

Comment: You should not assign model.fit to model. This becomes a history.

Answer (score 1):

In your case your model is overwritten by training history. Use some other variable name to keep training history.

```
history = model.fit(...)
```

Now you can use your model to predict.

Answer (score 1):

`model.fit(..)` returns a History object that contains the learning history of your model.

`model = model.fit(..)` overrides your convolutioan network with the History object.

You can remove the assignment alltogether and just use `model.fit()`. In case you would like to visualize the learning history, you can acces the values by typying `history = model.fit(..)`. After training you can visualize the results with this object. You can get the values saved by typing `history.history`.

To get predictions try `preds = model.predict(..)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are overwriting the model.

Try this

```
history = model.fit(...)
```

Then

```
predict = model.predict()
```